# How to change multiple build definitions into schedule builds

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration, schedule

we have around 300 TFS CI build definitions and now i want to change it into schedule build. Is it possible to change CI multiple Builds into scheduled.

Its really heck process to change one by one. I want some PowerShell or batch script to run the builds or any tool to change multiple TFS build definitions to schedule builds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TFS API to programmatically create and edit build definitions.  Here is an example:

http://blog.ehn.nu/2010/04/creating-a-build-definition-using-the-tfs-2010-api/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f

You should be able to change the trigger for multiple builds at once. I also created a set of powershell extensions to create/edit builds in bulk, but there is no CmdLet for the trigger yet, but have a look if you are interested in extending it (send me a pull request if you do ;)):
https://github.com/sanderaernouts/tfs-build-tools